# <main> inside <article> in HTML5

Tags: html

**Plot:**  When building a coupons website I realize that their can be content that is not unique to the page but should be used inside the `<main><article> ..here..</article></main>`.

**Problem:** Just because w3schools state :

> The content inside the  element should be unique to the
>   document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across
>   documents.

But i have content which will be inside article. Like every time for example `A coupon can be used by entering its code but a deal can only be activated by going to landing page.`
This will be repeated in every 'coupon' post I will publish.
So now what I tried to use was.

```
<main><article><main>Unique content</main>
<aside>A coupon can be used by entering its code but a deal can only be activated by going to landing page</aside></article></main>
```

But again :

```
 Note: There must not be more than one <main> element in a document.
 The <main> element must NOT be a descendent of an <article>, <aside>,
 <footer>, <header>, or <nav> element.
```

So what is the best way to format the UN-UNIQUE content inside `<main>` and/or `<article>`.

Comment: What w3schools is saying here, is outright wrong! See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-main-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` tag should be used to group those `article` and `aside` elements.

```
<main>
    <article>
        The unique document content.
    </article>
    <aside>
        Related content for that document.
    </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: So i already use <aside> for sidebar, won't that cause a problem. So will every content inside article tag will be considered main accept the aside one.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr - use your common sense :)

[This article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements#.3Caside.3E) on the *actual* w3 site has a good overview of what should go where. The overall structure is:

```
<body>

  <header>
    <!-- header content goes in here -->
  </header>

  <nav>
    <!-- navigation menu goes in here -->
  </nav>

  <section id="sidebar1">
    <!-- sidebar content goes in here -->
  </section>

  <main>
    <!-- main page content goes in here -->
  </main>

  <aside>
    <!-- aside content goes in here -->
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <!-- footer content goes in here -->
  </footer>

</body>
```

**Option 1 - `<section>`s**

They go on to say that `<section>`s, fairly obviously, can contain multiple `<articles>`, but that it is also possible to put `<section>`s *inside* an `<article>`, for example to define the introduction or summary:

```
<article>
  <section id="introduction">
  </section>

  <section id="content">
  </section>

  <section id="summary">
  </section>
</article>
```

So one option is to put a `<section id="content">` and `<section id="terms">` inside your article.

**Option 2 - `<footer>`s**

It does appear valid to use a `<footer>` for this sort of content. You said it is just for author, date, category, but w3 states in its [spec for `<footer>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element):

> A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, **copyright data, and the like.**

Your text is terms and conditions of a coupon, which could be considered as semantically similar to copyright data. It's a judgement call I think.

**Option 3 - `<div>`s et al...**

As a get-out, in the first link they do also [say about `<div>`s](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements#Where_does_that_leave_.3Cdiv.3E.3F):

> You should use [a div] when there is no other more suitable element available for grouping an area of content...

So if it *really* isn't clear what to use, another possibility could be:

```
<article>
  Blah blah
  <div class="terms"></div>
</article>
```

**Summary**

To be honest, after all this, it seems there is no definitive answer and sites are unlikely to become super-strict in how they semantically parse documents for a while yet, because they know there are legions of people out there who will do it completely wrong. If you just stick a `<p>` with the same terms in at the end of each article, it probably won't make any real difference because the main text is unique.

I personally think as long as you use your common sense and choose something which doesn't completely go against the recommendations, you can't go too wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the WHATWG (the informal group behind the HTML Living Document Standard), there is no problem in using a `main` element inside an `article`. The HTML Living Document says:

> There is no restriction as to the number of main elements in a document. Indeed, there are many cases where it would make sense to have multiple main elements. For example, a page with multiple article elements might need to indicate the dominant contents of each such element.

Consequently, you can write

```
<body>
 <header>My Page Header</header> 
 <main>
  <article><h1>My First Article</h1>
   <main>My first article's content...</main>
   <aside>A sidebar</aside>
  </article>
  <article><h1>My Second Article</h1>
   <main>My second article's content...</main>
   <aside>Another sidebar</aside>
  </article>
 </main>
</body>
```

However, the [W3C HTML 5.3 Draft disallows this](https://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#elementdef-main) and states that "There must not be more than one visible main element in a document."

This is an interesting case of a disagreement about a central element of HTML. Amazing! It seems that there is again a schism between W3C authors and the web/browser developer professionals behind the WHATWG. In such a case, I would go with the WHATWG.

Comment: WHATWG has a different opinion on the HTML 5 though -- they specifically disallow multiple `main` elements in a document. It's a conflicting point between the two standards bodies.

Comment: The HTML Living Document that I have cited is from the WHATWG. So,  you apparently want to say that W3C's HTML5 recommendation disallows multiple main elements. I looked it up and found that this is indeed the case. This is an interesting case of a disagreement about a central element of HTML. Amazing!

Comment: It would have been good to give the URL of the WHATWG document. Because [it states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) that you can’t use more than one `<main>` and you can’t use it in `<article>`:

“The main element represents the dominant contents of the document.
A document must not have more than one main element that does not have the hidden attribute specified.
A hierarchically correct main element is one whose ancestor elements are limited to html, body, div, form without an accessible name, and autonomous custom elements.”

Comment: Apparently, the WHATWG has changed their mind on this and followed the approach of W3C. You can still find their old statements, e.g., on https://www.sitepoint.com/defining-sample-sites-page-structure/

Answer (score -1):

I would go with something like this :

```
<main>
    <div class='article'>
        <article>Unique content</article>
        <footer>This coupon can be used only once..</footer>
    </div>
    <div class='article'>
        <article>Unique content</article>
        <footer>This coupon can be used only once..</footer>
    </div>
</main>
```

Anyway I think having multiple `<main>` tags is worse than having non-unique content in an `<article>` tag.

You can also take into consideration [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) for proper mapping your content with additional attributes ( `itemprop` ... )

Comment: There is meant to be only one <article> tag per page. Can;t get you. And which Schema.org/BlogPost itemprop will you suggest for something like this.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt where does it say there should be only 1 `<article>` per page?

Comment: There is no indication that you need to have only one article. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element . Take a look at the example in the specs. IMHO, w3schools have bad reputation for corectness (http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Rhumborl  Its on my page . I use it along with a cms which imposes one Article tag only for a single post. I am not talking about HTML5 here. Pardon me for confusion.

Comment: @drinchev W3Schools still has issues but they have at least worked on the primary concern developers had. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience.

Comment: Use `<footer>` inside `<article>` for the meta data that you want to provide. Yes I suggest [Schema.org/BlogPost](http://schema.org/blogPost)

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt :) Trust me on this one if you are novice. Worse than no documentation is bad documentation.

Comment: Its for author name, date and category. I have not researched and don't use footer in posts. Instead I markup them with schema and xfn markup like `class="entry-title" class="entry-meta" class="entry-content"`. But a good suggestion.